# Finding the equation of a function under the image of matrix A

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be a $2\times2$ matrix defined by
$$
A= 
\begin{pmatrix}
3& 0\\ 0& 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $(x,y)$ satisfy an equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. If $(x',y')$ is the image of $(x,y)$ under the matrix $A$, that is 
$$
A\; \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix}
$$
find the equation of $(x',y')$ and sketch its graph.

How do I go about doing this? Do I multiple matrix $A$ times the $xy$ matrix and then plugin what I get into the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and solve for $x$ and $y$? I think I can handle the graph once I know how to tackle the problem. Thanks in advance for any help! :D

Answer (score 0):

We have $x'=3x$ and $y'=2y$, hence $x^2+y^2=1\implies \frac{x'^2}{9}+\frac{y'^2}{4}=1$.  Thus the image of the circle is an ellipse.

Comment: First of all, thanks for replying. I appreciate your help! Second, I have a question. I don't understand why the x' and y' of the equation are divided by 9 and 4 respectively. I see that it just the square of 3 and 2 respectively, but I miss the logic on that one. If you could explain it to me, that would be much appreciated! Thanks! :D

Comment: First: Your'e welcome. Second: Since $x'=3x$ we have $x=\frac{x'}{3}$, similar $y=\frac{y'}{2}$.  Now feel free to plug in those results in $x^2+y^2=1$.